# React js versioning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sed

after React js build complete i would like to add ?time=2023-03-06-16:05:43 inside build/index.html

From:

```
<link href="/static/css/main.3678df32.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

To:

```
<link href="/static/css/main.3678df32.css?time=2023-03-06-16:05:43" rel="stylesheet">
```

using .sh file able to generate timestamp

VERSION=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)-$(date +%T)
sed -i -- "s/%VERSION%/$VERSION/g" build/index.html

Comment: Why is this tagged React? React is a JS library for creating UIs. This is likely a job for your bundler.

Comment: As pointed out above this would be build specific, eg.  `webpack`, `esbuild`, `rollup`, `parcel` etc...